# PowerShell Scraping From Website Slows Down Over Time (Pagination)

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

So I have a website that I want to scrape specific links from on multiple pages. I have successfully written a script to do just that:

```
$links = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.Generic.List[String]
for ($pageNumber = 1; $pageNumber -le 300; $pageNumber++) {
  $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://example.com/$pageNumber" -WebSession $cookie
  $items = $request.Links | Where-Object title -eq "Title" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty href
  $links.Add($items)
}
```

I create a new instance of a Generic List(T) with the String type. Then I have a For loop set up to go through 300 pages sequentially and add the links found on each page to the Generic List. It all works good and gets the job done, however this is where my question come in. For the first 20-25 loops it works great, at around 1.7-2.4 seconds/page. After that, it jumps to 5.7-6.8 seconds/page and I have no idea why. There's nothing that I can think of to be causing this random decrease in speed. I've even tried changing the type of collection. From HashSets all the way to Stacks. Also I've change namespaces entirely and tried concurrent and specialized collections, all to no avail.

If someone could give me some insight onto what's going on and how I could improve this behavior, I'd greatly appreciate it.

**Edit:** *After isolating the variables as @Persistent13 suggested it seems Invoke-WebRequest may be behind the slowdown. Can someone please elaborate on this?*

Comment: How are you profiling the code? How are you verifying the slowdown occurs  with the list object and not Invoke-WebRequest?

Comment: I use the Stopwatch class within the For loop. `$stopwatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()` at the beginning and `$stopwatch.Stop() $stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds` at the end. I haven't tested out whether the Invoke-WebRequest would be causing the slowdown. Actually I didn't even give it a thought.

Comment: After isolating the variables I think you may be right. It seems Invoke-WebRequest may be the culprit. Would you happen to know why this may be?